# Where do I find the assembly code for a procedure called in the GCC assembly output?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, disassembly

I've been playing around with the assembly output switch for GCC:

```
gcc -S -c helloworld.c
```

**helloworld.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**helloworld.s**:

```
    .file   "helloworld.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World!"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

In the output `helloworld.s` file,  I notice that the assembly command to output the "Hello World!" text is simply:

```
call puts
```

However, the `helloworld.s1` file doesn't have the **puts** procedure assembly code within it. Where would I be able to view this assembly code?

Comment: This is because your C program is expecting to be linked with the standard C runtime library, which has `puts()` in it. You can of course dig up the library file on your system as disassemble it, if you feel like it.

Comment: Would this be the `libc.so` file?

Comment: Yes, it is the `libc.so`; and I suggest to compile with `gcc -O -S -fverbose-asm`

Comment: I couldn't get objdump to disassemble `libc.so`, but I did find the code in `libc.a` under the *<puts>* section: `objdump -d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a`

Comment: Debian uses eglibc which is open-source, so you can see actual C source code of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502403/where-do-i-find-the-assembly-code-for-a-procedure-called-in-the-gcc-assembly-out#comment21949969_15502403) mentioned:

> This is because your C program is expecting to be linked with the standard C
>   runtime library, which has `puts()` in it. You can of course dig up the library
>   file on your system as disassemble it, if you feel like it.

So I used **objdump** to disassemble `libc.a` and found the assembly code under the `<puts>` section: `objdump -d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a`

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**: this is not actually an answer to the original question, but since it's getting upvoted the info seems to be useful, so...

---

It's an optimization by GCC. Since your string does not contain any formatting characters and ends with a newline, GCC replaces the call with `puts` which produces the same output but is much faster (since it doesn't need to scan the string for formatting specifiers). Try something like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Hello World!\nargc=%d", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

And you will see your `printf` in the assembly.

Comment: The question seems to be "Where is the assembly source for `puts`?", not "Why is `puts` used instead of `printf`?"

Comment: Ah, indeed you're right. I'd edit it to change the answer but that would be stealing votes from people who already answered in the comments to OP...

Comment: The OP did [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502403/where-do-i-find-the-assembly-code-for-a-procedure-called-in-the-gcc-assembly-out/15603345#15603345) with `objdump -d` on `libc.a`, so the question does have an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

**answer**:

use the gcc flags `-fno-builtin`.

**Explaination**:

To improve the performance, GCC, Glibc will together make some modification to the standard C library. Because GCC and Glibc works together for almost all the userspace applications, so the builtin function is turned on default, which will convert `printf()` function call with only one parameter with `puts()` function call.

You can also tell GCC not to convert  a specific builtin function call by using flags like `-fno-builtin-printf`. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is  the complete list of the builtin functions which you can stop GCC to convert.

[here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) is the detail explanation of the flag.